# How to insert values into related models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models as follows:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    startDate = models.DateField()
    endDate = models.DateField()
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    def generateReservationItems(self):
        for d in range((endDate - startDate).days):
           reservationItem= ReservationItems(reservationDate=d, count = count)
           reservationItem.save()

class ReservationItems(models.Model):
    reservationDate = models.DateField();
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

class Reservation represents a package of dates (range of dates), and the class ReservationItems stores every single date exists in Reservation class.
I built  'generateReservationItems()'function to be automatically invoked when a Reservation object is saved. The function inserts number of items equals to the different between startDate and endDate. for example: if startDate = Mars 6 2020, and endDate = Mars 10 2020, 5 items will be inserted in ReservationItems:

```
Mars 6 2020
Mars 7 2020
Mars 8 2020
Mars 9 2020
Mars 10 2020
```

But Reservation objects are inserted successfully without inserting the items into reservationItems. I don't know how to make the 'generateReservationItems()' invoked once a reservation object is created.
any ideas please to do it, or if there and other effective methods to perform such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

post_save signal is your friend:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Reservation(models.Model):
    ...


@receiver(post_save, sender=Reservation, created=True)
def invokeGenerateReservationItems(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.generateReservationItems()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable reply. Now i get this error : 
NameError: name 'Reservation' is not defined'

Comment: It works well. i just added the App name before Reservation: AppName.Reservation.